# how to find locations on an xml file that are within radius distance of longitude and latitude

Tags: xml, google-maps

I have searched around here but I haven't been able to find anything close to what I am looking for. I have a working map that sort markers based on some criteria. I want to introduce a new criteria whereby I'll able to search within radius distance of longitude and latitude.

Now my question is since I already have a way to generate an xml file(through mysql/php), is there a way to calculate distances from longitude and latitude information existing in my php/mysql generated xml file without having to re-recode this xml file. All approaches I have seen calculate the distance from lat and lng information stored in a database.

In other words how do I pass lat and lng information to the distance calculating formula given I have an existing lat and lng information on an xml file. By the way,my php/mysql generated xml file can be viewed here http://daressalaam.co.tz/execute.php

Asante!(Thank you!)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about downloading this data into JavaScript where you use the Google Maps API to work with it, or are you wanting to do these distance calculations on your server? (My answer below assumes you want to do the calculations in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you can possibly do it, change your PHP code to generate JSON instead of XML. JSON is just as easy to generate from PHP as XML is - simply create a PHP array with the contents you want and call [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on it. There are plenty of examples on that page. And JSON is *much* easier to work with in JavaScript than XML.

For example, if we take an excerpt from your XML file and put it in JSON format instead, it would look like this:

```
{
    "markers": [
        {
            "section": "Female",
            "name": "Colorado Hooper",
            "address": "1415 Market St ",
            "gender": "Female",
            "graduation": 1996,
            "degree": "MS Computer Information Systems",
            "lat": 39.748177,
            "lng": -105.000504,
            "zipcode": "80202",
            "type": ""
        },
        {
            "section": "Female",
            "name": "Willow Weiss",
            "address": "259 E Broad St ",
            "gender": "Female",
            "graduation": 2001,
            "degree": "MS Computer Science",
            "lat": 33.957802,
            "lng": -83.374657,
            "zipcode": "30601",
            "type": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The beauty of using JSON is that you can then access the data directly in JavaScript instead of having to call a bunch of parsing functions for every element and attribute you want to use. It saves a bunch of work and makes the JavaScript code cleaner and easier to understand.

You can also use the correct data types: note that the `lat` and `lng` values are numbers and not strings, and the same for `graduation` (if you want the year to be a number). But be careful: zip codes are not numbers; they should always be handled as strings. (And if it's a problem, you could always continue to use strings for everything and convert to numbers when needed in the JavaScript code.)

Does that sound like something you could do, or are you required to use XML for some reason?

Now skipping ahead to the distance calculation... You didn't say what distances you want to calculate, but if you have any two lat/lng coordinates, it's easy to get the distance between them using the `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()` function from the [Maps API's Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical). As an example, suppose you had the JSON object above stored in a variable named `json`, and you wanted to get the distance between the first two entries in the file. It might go something like this:

```
var computeDistanceBetween = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween;

var markerA = json.markers[0];
var markerB = json.markers[1];
var latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng( markerA.lat, markerA.lng );
var latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng( markerB.lat, markerB.lng );
var distance = computeDistanceBetween( latLngA, latLngB );
```

Even if you use XML, the distance calculation would be similar, but you would have to do the XML parsing to get the data attributes you need.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond. I'll work on your suggestions and communicate my progress!And to clarify about the distance, I'm looking to do something similar to a google store locator example...I want to display markers(corresponding to lat and lng) that are within some radius distance from a given zipcode...so say I select some zipcode and radius on my dropdown menu I should be able display all markers that fall within the selected radius.